# How to display a json array in a textbox using c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list, deserialization

I would like to know how to deserialize a json array and display it on a richTextbox. I'm calling an API to get the JSON array. Can someone help me out with this. I have got it into a List but i'm not sure whether i've done it properly.

Form1.cs

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    runapi("http://localhost:8080/json_coordinates");
}

public void runapi(string api)
{
        try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(api);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();               

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            obj.DeserializeJsonDes(json);          
            // Help me fill it up to display data on the richTextBox    
            //richTextBox1.Text = responseFromServer;
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
}
```

Class JsonDes

```
class JsonDes
{ 
    public List<JsonDes> name { get; set; }
    public List<JsonDes> coordinates { get; set; }

    public List<JsonDes> DeserializeJsonDes(string jsonArray)
    {
        //return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonDes>(json);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonDes>>(jsonArray);
    }        

}
```

The original JSON being passed in has the structure:

```
[{'name' : 'Train 1', 'coordinates' : '38.892802, -77.061945'},
{'name' : 'Train 2', 'coordinates' : '38.941686, -77.134043'}]
```

Comment: What is the output, what should the output be? Also the title doesn't match the questions body

Comment: And what is the JSON you're receiving. Your class definition doesn't show much

Comment: My Json array looks like this 
[{'name' : 'Train 1', 'coordinates' : '38.892802, -77.061945'},{'name' : 'Train 2', 'coordinates' : '38.941686, -77.134043'}]
I want to display the names and coordinates in the richTextBox

Comment: @AshanWijenayake we want to see `JsonDes` structure

Comment: @Navonel If I have a json array like the one I posted on the comment, how could I display the data on it in a TextBox or a RichTextBox using JsonConvert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class structure is not clear.However without knowing that I will try to answer the question.

What you can do is to cast a dynamic type like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>()` to deserialize this string into a dynamic type then simply access its properties in the usual way.

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonArray);
```

Now you cane access `results[0].Name`.

Alternatively you can return object of type `JArray`.

`dynObj = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonArray);`

Then iterate over this object like

```
 foreach (JObject item in dynObj)
 {
      access now item["Your Property Name"]
 }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That works for me. Thank you very much. <dynamic> fixed it

Comment: how can I display the output on a text box or a list box? I get errors.

Comment: I got it. Thanks, had a problem with casting.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be first define your class to fit the shape of one record in the data being retrieved.

In this case:

```
public class JsonDes
{
   public string name { get; set;
   public string coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

From there, you just need to use [Newtonsoft's Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize it.

```
public static List<JsonDes> Convert(string json)
{
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonDes>>(json);
}
```